# Search form generates blank page

Tags: search

I am trying to set up a search form in my website. Followed [this tutorial](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/search-form) on builtwithcraft documentation website.

So in my top navigation bar I include this code

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="{{ url('/oeuvres/_results') }}">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Recherche">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Go"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> </span></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

And then the result page:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block main %}
    {% include "includes/_topNav" %}

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Résultats</h1>

                {% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
                {% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).section('oeuvres') %}

                {% if entries|length %}
                    <p>{{ entries|length }} Votre recherche:</p>
                    <ul>
                        {% for entry in entries %}
                            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% else %}
                    <p>Votre recherche “{{ query }}” n'a donné aucun résultat.</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% include "includes/_javaScript" %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have no idea what is wrong, it seems that the "q" param is passing through the result page (the address line is for example: http://www.example.com/oeuvres/_results?q=routes
But the page is totally blank. Meaning nothing gets generated between the body tags. (not even the template tags...

I can't find what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates starting with an underscore character is by default denied direct access in Craft (resulting in a 404 not found error). I guess that renaming your template to "results" should fix it.

Comment: that was it! Thanks. Strange enough, my 404 template is not showing up at all...

Comment: Check that you don't have any rewrite rules in your .htaccess concerning 404 handling. If there is a redirect in there, the request doesn't reach Craft at all.